# Rendering HTML instead of JSON: Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an API that I am trying to call from a method within my application. Even though I am calling the API using the json format, and I am setting the respond_to to JSON, it still renders as HTML.

This is the method in the controller:

```
def index
  @moviedetails = Moviedetail.all
  respond_to :json
end
```

This is the API call from the method

```
def self.searchHighestRating()
  url="https://ruby-rsudding.c9users.io/moviedetails.json"
  response = HTTParty.get(url)
  responsebody = JSON.parse(response.body)
  return responsebody
end
```

Any thoughts around how I could resolve this?

Comment: and your route?

Comment: resources :moviedetails

Comment: even changing it to the following does not help:  resources :moviedetails, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }

Comment: and what about `render :json => @moviedetails` instead `respond_to :json`?

Answer (score 0):

Put render json: instead and make sure the answer is actually coming back in json

Comment: I have added render json: in the controller, but it still responds in HTML.

Comment: def index
    @moviedetails = Moviedetail.all
    render json:
  end